# how to understand minkowski's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can't understand this from geometric intuition. I don't see why any centrally symmetric shape has to be constrained with any lattice. they seem irrelevant to me.

```
Area(S) > $4\delta(L)$
```

couldn't S just be of any area ?

I must miss something here.

Comment: Centrally symmetric convex shape. Convexity is important.

Comment: Have you seen the proof? The proof, to me, is fairly intuitive - it explains why the factor of $4$ is there, for example (and why the factor would be $2^n$ in $n$ dimension.)

Comment: Just read the proof (and note the convexity condition). What part of it is unclear?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews S is dfined in $R^2$, so why S even have to be bigger than 1 lattice cell. isn't 1 lattice cell centrally symmetric and convex ?

Comment: The point is that *any* set which is symmetric and convex and big enough area has a non-zero lattice point, not that *some* such set exists. There are such subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ of area $4|L|$ without non-zero lattice points.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks, I see the point now.

Answer (score 0):

The shape is convex as well, this is pretty important. A convex, symmetric around the origin, body is constrained so.